# Does $S^1 \vee S^1$ have a cover homotopically equivalent to the wedge sum of $k$ circles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm stuck on the following problem: Is it true that for every $k$ the space $S^1 \vee S^1$ has a covering space homotopically equivalent to the wedge sum of $k$ circles? I don't really have a good intuition on covering spaces or the difference between homotopy and homemorphisms so any tips on approaching this would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly recommend you brush up on covering spaces and the difference between homotopy and homeomorphisms. It is very difficult to answer your question if you lack the basic requirements to understand any such answer.

Comment: I'd recommend pg 57-58 of Hatcher's 'Algebraic Topology' for a discussion of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k\geq 2$ here is a way to get them. 
 One class of covering spaces for $S^1\vee S^1$ comes from covering spaces of one of the $S^1$'s and attaching copies of the other $S^1$ at each lifted base point.  That is, a space which is an $S^1$ along with $n\geq 1$ copies of $S^1$ wedged to it at different points.  This space is homotopy equivalent to $n+1$ wedged $S^1$'s by way of collapsing $1$-cells.

For $k=0$, the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ is contractible, so it is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of zero $S^1$'s.

For $k=1$, you can take the covering space associated with the subgroup generated by one of the generators.  This looks like a circle with two "leaves" of the Cayley graph for $F_2$ attached.  Each leaf is contractible to the basepoint.

Comment: It's actually true for all $k\ge 0$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Oops, you're completely right.